# Highcharts - margins update on window resize

Tags: javascript, highcharts, window-resize

I am creating an areaspline graph with `highcharts` with a specific margin, which I would like to update on window `resize`. This is the code related to the graph:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.chart({
    chart: {
      renderTo : options.element,
      marginLeft: -calcOutsideMargin(),
      marginRight: -calcOutsideMargin(),
      backgroundColor:'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)',
      type: 'areaspline'
    },
    plotOptions: {              
      areaspline: {
        animation: false,
        states: { hover: { enabled: false } },
        fillOpacity: 0.5,
        marker:{
            states:{
                select: {
                    radius: 5,
                    fillColor: '#ff0000',
                    lineColor: '#404759'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: series
});
```

And this is the function that should define the dimensions of the margins:

```
calcOutsideMargin: function() {
    return ((window.addEventListener('resize', window.innerWidth) / 5 ) / 2) + 5;
}
```

Unluckily I get an error which says that the expected length is `NaN`, and if I use `window.innerWidth` it is not updated. Do you have an idea on how to solve this issue and make the margin updated on window resize?

Thanks in advance for your replies!

**EDIT**

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pheh8bqf/)

Comment: Mb you can change margin for wrapper div? Can you create example at jsfiddle?

Comment: I have tried it but it is not working and I have updated the question so that you can have a look at it ;)

Comment: The jsFiddle is working for me and the graph changes size when I resize.

Comment: I have updated the `calcOutsideMargin()` function with a `console.log()`. As you can see, if I resize the page it is not called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some unworking code. `charts.marginLeft`, `charts.marginRight` and `charts.width` do not accept functions for changing the sizes in real time; they accept only variables and function results. You'll have to manually handle the window `resize` event and do all the work there. You can then change these parameters by using the `chart.update` method.

My working example with the chart at the center. Resize the window and check both console for the window resize event, and the chars resize animation:

```
$(function () {
    //var chart;

    function calcOutsideMargin() {
        console.log('margin resize', Date.now());
        return ((window.innerWidth / 5 ) / 2);
    };

    $(window).resize(function() {
        var margin = calcOutsideMargin(),
            width =  window.innerWidth - (margin * 2);
        window.chart.update({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                marginLeft: margin, // (vw/5)/2
                marginRight: margin, // (vw/5)/2
                width: width
            }
        });
    });

    var margin = calcOutsideMargin(),
        width =  window.innerWidth - (margin * 2);

    $(document).ready(function() {
        window.chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
              renderTo: 'container',
              marginLeft: margin, // (vw/5)/2
              marginRight: margin, // (vw/5)/2
              width: width, // window.addEventListener("resize", window.innerWidth),
              spacingBottom: 6,
              spacingTop: 0,
              backgroundColor:'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)',
              type: 'areaspline'
            },
            title: { text: '' },
            legend: { enabled: false },
            xAxis: { visible: false, allowDecimals: false },
            yAxis: { visible: false },
            tooltip: { enabled: false },
            credits: { enabled: false },
            plotOptions: {              
              areaspline: {
              animation: false,
              states: { hover: { enabled: false } },
              fillOpacity: 0.5,
              marker:{
                states:{
                  select: {
                  radius: 5,
                  fillColor: '#ff0000',
                  lineColor: '#404759'
                }
                }
              }
              },
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'F',
                data: [6 , 11, 32, 110, 235, 369, 640, 1005, 1436 ]
            }, {
                name: 'C',
                data: [5, 25, 50, 120, 150, 200, 426, 660, 869, 1060]
            }]
        });
    });
});
```

I have also added this CSS code just to have the chart align at the center:

```
#container > div {
    margin:auto;
}
```

You can check my full working example here: http://zikro.gr/dbg/html/highcharts.html

Answer (score 0):

You can also resize container:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('#container').css({
        "marginLeft": calcOutsideMargin() + "px",
        "marginRight": calcOutsideMargin() + "px"
    });
});
```